# Configuration of NameVirtualHosts

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost, apache-2.2

Hi, this is my first post, hope you have patience about my novice skills :P

I try to configure my apache2 server (ubuntu) using NameVirtualHost. At this moment i have 3 domains pointing at my static ip; domain1.dyndns.org, domain2.com, domain3.com

My wish is that domain2.com and domain3.com will be configured as Virtualhost pointing to their special directory. All other HTTP-requests like accessing my router (domain1.dyndns.org:8080) remote will be pointed to the domain1.dyndns.org and accessed from there.

For now i have a issue from the apache-server when restarting and i cant see the problem, notice i dont have the default file enabled, only domain2.com and domain3.com, if i enable default the other domains points to my www directory, i still dont understand the problem:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
* Restarting web server apache2                                                
[Wed Jul 06 13:16:24 2011] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
... waiting [Wed Jul 06 13:16:26 2011] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
```

This is my configuration right now:

**ports.conf:**

```
Listen 80
Listen 443
```

**/Sites-available/default:**

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**/Sites-available/domain2.com:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain2.com
ServerAlias www.domain2.com
ServerAdmin contact@domain2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2.com/

<Directory /var/www/domain2.com/>
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
# Don't show indexes for directories
Options -Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**/Sites-available/domain3.com:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain3.com
ServerAlias www.domain3.com
ServerAdmin contact@domain3.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain3.com/

<Directory /var/www/domain3.com/>
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
# Don't show indexes for directories
Options -Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I still have problem with the ports, I put NameVirtualHost *:80 in my ports.conf and it works well without any warnings but the other problem is still there. I want my domain1.dyndns.org take care of all service requests as domain1.dyndns.org:8080 instead of domain2.com:8080 etc. I dont understand how to configure this.

Answer (score 2):

In your `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` file ensure that you have a [NameVirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) statement. This tells Apache that it should expect virtual hosts on the designated IP address or all addresses `*` and port.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```